# Chrome infected

Tags: google-chrome, popup-ads

I have Chrome browser installed and sometime in the last week it starts randomly open popup windows as I clicked in different sites. I suspect I'd been infected by some trojan.

I've scanned my machine with ClamAV and found nothing.

Can someone tell me how to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Do you mind providing further information about the sites that you visited? your current chrome version and the plugins/extensions that you have installed. It will also help if you let us know what is the pop up window showing (the link) in order to see if this is such an infection or a problem caused by your current chrome configuration/extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that you might not have the pop-up blocker turned on on Chrome. Now to activate it, here is what you do.

Type `chrome://chrome/settings/content` on your addressbar (in chrome), then scroll down until you find  **Pop-ups** there check `Do not allow any site to show pop-ups` option.

If problem persists, I'd suggest re-installing Chrome.

Hope this was of some help.

Comment: If you wish, you can edit your answer to include the possible need of creating a [new profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059). While it may have been implied by "re-installing", it may not be obvious. A mere re-installation doesn't affect the existing profile which may be the cause of the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **chrome://settings** or just go to settings, and go to the very bottom of the page click advance settings and then click reset to default browser settings.

that might work. good luck

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you installed any suspicious chrome extensions?
   Type
   chrome://extensions/
   in URL, have a check.
2. Press **Ctrl+Shift+J** to open the chrome developer **console**,
   sometimes it will output some useful information.
3. Further, check the **network** column of the **console**,
   the trojan may come from network.

Make a screenshot of it ,so you can provide more details 
to let others help you.

[screen shot of chrome developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI6BR.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's very normal to get pop-ups in browsers nowadays. You can activate, as others suggested, the native pop-up blocker in chrome. I, however, suggest you use an ad-blocker, which, as the name states, blocks ads (pop-ups included).

My vote goes to ublock origin:

https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/releases

or

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm